# JS replace class on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fontawesome

имею следующую структуру

```
<td><a href="#" id="123" class="file_not_find">
    <i class="fa fa-times" style="font-size:24px"></I>
    </a>
 </td>
```

Забираю ID по нажатию на ячейки, просьба, подсказать, как дополнительно корректно заменить `class` в данном случае, пытаюсь следующим скриптом

```
$('#table tbody').on('click', '.file_not_find', function(){
            var id = $(this).closest('.file_not_find').attr('id');
            $(this).closest('.fa fa-times').removeClass('.fa fa-times');
            $(this).addClass('fa fa-spinner fa-pulse');
            console.log(id)
            $.ajax({
                url: '/dwnld',
                type: 'post',
                data: {name_file: id}
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#table tbody .file_not_find').click(function(){
            let id = $(this).attr('id');
            $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-times');
            $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-spinner fa-pulse');
            console.log(id)
            $.ajax({
                url: '/dwnld',
                type: 'post',
                data: {name_file: id}
            })
        })
```